# Is it possible to use $subscribe or watch inside the store itself?

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I want to watch the store and make a new api call (use store action) each time when a part of the store changes. How can I implement this watcher inside the (`defineStore()`) store itself ?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Also interested to know. Thx

Comment: @jimmybondy yep, check this out: [watch from inside a store?](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/794) discussed in github.

Comment: I already saw that discussion, but from my perspective its missing a full working example.  I need actions and getters and don't know how they can be used with setup stores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a [setup store](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#setup-stores), you could use this syntax. This would watch just one state property, then trigger a side effect based on that state property changing:

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { ref, watch } from "vue";

export const useCartStore = defineStore("cart", () => {
    // state
    const items = ref([]);
    let cartIsEmpty = ref(false);

    // actions
    function emptyCart() {
        // *logic here to empty the cart*
        cartIsEmpty.value = true;
    }

    // watch
    watch(cartIsEmpty, ()=> {
        if (cartIsEmpty.value === true) {
            fetchItems();
        }
    });
});
```